Removing Widgets From CentralWidget PyQt6
Removing widgets without really deleting them from layouts are possible in PyQt6, apparently. However, there is no documented or provided way of really forcefully deleting widgets, (even more of a special case; from a CentralWidget) and essentially making it cease to exist.
I had rendered my application frameless and made the frameless window completely transparent using self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint) and self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground). In short, the CentralWidget;
container_frame = QWidget() 
container_frame.setObjectName('Container')
self.setCentralWidget(container_frame)

is now SEEMINGLY my new window. I added some sign-in widgets into container_frame but of course, in any normal app, after clicking login in an authentication area, the application should direct you to its actual contents. To do so, it would probably need to get rid of the sign-in widgets in the container_frame . Since in my context I really do not need sign-in widgets in my application I'm planning of just chucking them in the bin, flushing it down the toilet. But I don't know how to do that and questions online don't align with my case very well, nobody having to render their original window transparent and giving a new one - a CentralWidget. How do I delete the sign-in widgets?
I tried finding solutions in several Q&A websites to no avail. For some context, I'm trying to delete the sign-in widgets in the triggered function;
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRect, QRectF, QEvent, QDate, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QProgressDialog
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont, QCursor

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('You should not see this')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.resize(QApplication.primaryScreen().availableSize().width(), 
                    QApplication.primaryScreen().availableSize().height() + 4)
        container_frame = QWidget()
        container_frame.setObjectName('Container')
        container_frame.setStyleSheet('''
            #Container {
                background: qlineargradient(x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2:1, stop:0 #65ade9, stop:1 #0c75cd);
                border-radius: 25px;
            }
        ''')
        self.setCentralWidget(container_frame)
        title = QLabel('Sign Into My Kewl And Epik App', container_frame)
        title.setFont(QFont('', 40, 700))
        title.setStyleSheet('color: white') 
        title.move(120, 120)
        username_label = QLabel('Username', container_frame)
        username_label.setFont(QFont('', 20, 400))
        username_label.setStyleSheet('color: white; letter-spacing: 1px;')
        username_label.move(120, 240)
        username_input = QLineEdit(container_frame)
        username_input.setFont(QFont('', 20, 400))
        username_input.setStyleSheet('''
            QLineEdit {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 2px solid white;
                color: white;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
        ''')
        username_input.resize(300, 30)
        username_input.move(120, 270)
        username_input.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.focus_password(password_input))
        password_label = QLabel('Password', container_frame)
        password_label.setFont(QFont('', 20, 400))
        password_label.setStyleSheet('color: white; letter-spacing: 1px;')
        password_label.move(120, 360)
        password_input = QLineEdit(container_frame)
        password_input.setFont(QFont('', 20, 400))
        password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
        password_input.setStyleSheet('''
            QLineEdit {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 2px solid white;
                color: white;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
        ''')
        password_input.resize(300, 30)
        password_input.move(120, 390)
        password_input.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.triggered())
        button = QPushButton('Authenticate', container_frame)
        button.setFont(QFont('', 20, 400))
        button.setStyleSheet('''
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #0c5a9c;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: white;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
        ''')
        button.resize(300, 55)
        button.move(120, 480)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.triggered())
        button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        container_frame.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.remove_focus(event, username_input, password_input)

    def focus_password(self, password_input): password_input.setFocus()
    def remove_focus(self, event, *fields): [field.clearFocus() for field in fields]
    def triggered(self): print('Authentication triggered. ')


# Run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    erm = QApplication([])
    app = App()
    app.show()
    erm.exec() 


The transparency aspect is irrelevant, the behavior wouldn't change. Just call setCentralWidget() with a new container. Also look into QStackedWidget.

I understand that I can call setCentralWidget() with a new container of my app contents. But where would my sign-in page go, the container_frame and all those widgets inside it?

The setCentralWidget() docs say: "QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time". This means that if a previous central widget existed, it will be deleted along with all its children. See the Object Trees & Ownership documentation.

Does this mean I could just declare a new container and move on, and PyQt6 will just delete all my previous widgets? Could you provide me an example on how to implement this in the triggered function, please?

Yes, that's exactly what I wrote. There's no need for an example, just create a new widget and call setCentralWidget() with it in triggered. Note: PyQt is a Python binding around the Qt library; PyQt doesn't delete the central widget, Qt does. In any case, as said, you should look into QStackedWidget, which is the preferred choice for this kind of situations, and it also allows you the possibility of "going back" to the first "page" (for instance, if you want to provide some form of "log out").
